# VM Performance on Different Hardware

Tags: virtualization, performance

I just bought a new server to act as a Hyper-V host for our current VMs.  The hardware specs are better than our existing server (faster CPU speed, fast disk IO, etc) and I expect to see our VMs performing better.  Instead of relying upon end user perception, I wanted to provide data to management that the VMs are performing better.  How can I achieve that?  Would I use PerfMon counters and which ones?  Are  there other tools out there I can use to show speed differences between the two hosts?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Management won't care about technical details. They aren't useless: They can help you plan for upcoming upgrades and help you understand when you need to start budgeting for additional hardware, but they are uninteresting in their raw form unless they look spectacular compared to the old machine's performance when displayed in a diagram.

To impress the higher-ups, think of a benchmark that's relevant to what your company does: For example, if you have developers building software, record build times on the old and on the new machine. Or if you create large periodical financial reports, time those.

Answer (score 0):

Lead with the executive summary, not detailed data. For example:

- End user system response time metrics are being met, it is fast.
- User tickets complaining of slowness are down this month.
- Capacity exists to handle growth exceeding the organization's expansion plans.
- Hardware was nearing end of life, this was necessary to keep supported and secure.

Of course, have data to back all these up. Measurable, focused on your users, with the return on investment. Again for example:

- 99.9 percentile response time on the web site is less than 500 ms, keeping customers from clicking away.
- Daily reports are ready by 06:00, reducing waiting.
- Graph of total capacity (VMs, users, transactions, whatever) for old, new, and projected future organization needs.
- Hours of downtime prevented via vendor hardware support, multiplied by cost of being down.

Notice the lack of host level performance metrics. Those do not really matter to non-sysadmin people who just want to use the system.

Maybe they will help prove the point, 90% CPU utilization is relatively straightforward to understand. But mostly host resource utilization data is for the sysadmin to analyze.